# Initializing Raphael object with jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, raphael

In Raphael docs, we init Raphael with:

```
var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById("notepad"), 320, 200);
```

I want to select my class with jQuery and turn it to Raphael, so my thought is:

```
var paper = Raphael($(".myClass"), 320, 200);
```

But I get `TypeError: b is undefined` in Raphael.js. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
var paper = Raphael($(".myClass")[0], 320, 200);
```

The `$` function returns an array-type object of HTML elements, so use `[0]` to get the first.